# Spark data processing

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I want to process Big Dataset using Spark and Scala as part of my analysis process.

**Sample Input**

```
id, related_ids
a, "b,e,f,i,j"
b, "e,i,j,k,l"
c, "f,i,j,m,n"
d, "c,i,g,m,s"
```

**Sample Output**

a, "c,d" 
b, "a,c"
c, "a,b" 
d, "NULL"

I thought of creating a data frame on top of that doing operations but I'm not able to move further after creating the data frame.

```
{
    val input11 = sc.textFile(inputFile).map(x=>x.replaceAll("\"",""))
    val input22 = input11.map(x=>x.split(",")).collect {
    case Array(id,name,name1, name2, name3, name4) => Record(id.toInt, name.toInt, name1.toInt, name2.toInt, name3.toInt, name4.toInt)
    }

            val tbl = input22.toDF()
            tbl.registerTempTable("rawData")
            val res = sqlContext.sql("select name from rawData")
    }
    case class Record(id: Int, name: Int, name1 : Int, name2 : Int, name3 :  Int, name4 : Int)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get exactly what you want with the following code:

I import your data:

```
val d = sc.parallelize(Seq(1 -> Seq(2,5,6,10,11), 
                           2 -> Seq(5,10,11,15,16), 
                           3-> Seq(6,10,11,17,21), 
                           4 -> Seq(3,10,12,17,22))
```

Then defines a function that will enumerate all the 2-tuples that can be created from an ordered list.

```
def expand(seq : Seq[Int]): Seq[(Int, Int)] = 
    if (seq.isEmpty) 
         Seq[(Int, Int)]() 
    else 
         seq.tail.map(x=> seq.head -> x) ++ expand(seq.tail)
```

example :

```
scala> expand(Seq(1,2,3,4))
res27: Seq[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,3), (2,4), (3,4))
```

And the final calculation would go as follows:

```
val p = 2
d
     .flatMapValues(x=>x)
     .map(_.swap)
     .groupByKey
     .map(_._2)
     .flatMap(x=>expand(x.toSeq.sorted))
     .map(_ -> 1)
     .reduceByKey(_+_)
     .filter(_._2>= p)
     .map(_._1)
     .flatMap(x=> Seq(x._1 -> x._2, x._2 -> x._1))
     .groupByKey.mapValues(_.toArray.sorted)
```

which yields:

```
Array((1,Array(2, 3)), (2,Array(1, 3)), (3,Array(1, 2, 4)), (4,Array(3)))
```

Note by the way that you made a mistake in your exemple, 4 and 3 have 2 elements in common (10 and 17). With p=3, you get:

```
Array((1,Array(2, 3)), (2,Array(1)), (3,Array(1)))
```

To get even the lines who do not have any "co_relations", join with the original data.

```
d
    .leftOuterJoin(connexions)
    .mapValues(x=> x._1 -> x._2.getOrElse(null))
```

And you finally get (with p=3):

```
Array((1,(List(2, 5, 6, 10, 11),Array(2, 3))), 
      (2,(List(5, 10, 11, 15, 16),Array(1))), 
      (3,(List(6, 10, 11, 17, 21),Array(1))), 
      (4,(List(3, 10, 12, 17, 22),null)))
```

Nonetheless, if you want to study connexions between your data points in a more general way, I encourage you to have a look to the Graph API of spark. You might for instance be interested in computing the connected components of your graph. ( [GraphX](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html) )

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation @Oli. I tried to up vote the answer, however I don't have permission to do that. I accepted the answer.

Comment: is it possible to the same operations on input file instead of `val d = sc.parallelize(Seq(1 -> Seq(2,5,6,10,11), 
                           2 -> Seq(5,10,11,15,16), 
                           3-> Seq(6,10,11,17,21), 
                           4 -> Seq(3,10,12,17,22))` reading the data from Seq. I mean reading the **sample input** from a file.

Comment: Of course, there are different options. If you want to read your exact sample file, you may use spark's CSV reader:

`spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("hdfs:///tmp/test.csv").rdd.map(x=> x.getAs[Int]("id") -> x.getAs[String]("related_ids").split(",").map(_.toInt))`